# How to add Syntax Highlighting in Vim for .ini files

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, ini

I recently started using Vi Improved and being a Rainmeter Skin Specialist, when editing my .ini files I can't find a way to add syntax highlight for such files. I searched for a lot of time on stack and git and turned up to nothing. Requesting help at the latest.

TLDR; Need .ini file syntax highlighting for Vim

Comment: I guess file syntax highlighting for `.ini` already exists. Try `set syntax=dosini` if Vim has one. Mine is Neovim, so I am not completely sure.

Comment: I wanted to highlight Python's `poetry.lock` file. I just needed `set filetype=dosini`   Thanks @j1-lee I'm not sure that this lock file is a 100% ini file, but it looks nice.

Answer (score 6):

To force the current file to use ini syntax highlighting:

```
:set syntax=dosini
```

The `dosini` part is the tricky part as it doesn't come to mind. I tried stuff like `syntax=ini` and started Googling when that didn't work. The top comment on the question answered it, which is the solution above.

Comment: Cool, this worked for me too: Proxmox VE 8.1.4 + empty `~/.vimrc` :P

Answer (score 3):

Vim already has syntax highlighting for `*.ini` files.

- If your Vim is reasonably recent, say 8.0 and up, and you didn't set anything up with regards to Vim (no `$HOME\_vimrc`, nothing), then your `*.ini` files should be highlighted without any human intervention at all.

  The screenshot below was taken in a test VM with a basic Vim without any setup:

  [image: vim]
- If you have already customised Vim, with a `$HOME\_vimrc` file and/or with a `$HOME\vimfiles` directory, then you are in full control, which means that the automatic stuff described above is no longer done for you anymore. And being in full control of Vim pretty much requires that you learn it properly and configure it as you go.

  Having ***EITHER*** of the following lines in your `$HOME\_vimrc` or `$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc` is going to give you automatic syntax highlighting for any recognised filetype:

  ```
  syntax enable
  syntax on
  ```

Comment: OK, I get it, but now I understand that I am currently using vim in kali wsl in windows terminal and all files except .ini highlights automatically even though I have syntax on in my vimrc.  Cheers mate and thank you